# How to show a flash message before rendering the page while controller takes some time to process

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 5 and Flash.
Here is a method in my controller.
The query takes some 10-15 seconds to execute no matter the db tuning, due to some large volumes of data to be processed.
I want to have a flash message telling something like "Processing ... " before the @result is handed over to the view with the same name to be rendered.

```
  def monthly_measurements
    if user_signed_in?
      @query = "
        SELECT  to_char(scheduled_on, 'yyyy-mm') as year_month,
                get_measurements_count_by_year_month(to_char(scheduled_on, 'yyyy-mm'),NULL) as monthly_total,
                get_measurements_count_by_year_month(to_char(scheduled_on, 'yyyy-mm'),'Completed') as monthly_completed,
                get_measurements_count_by_year_month(to_char(scheduled_on, 'yyyy-mm'),'Not Completed') as monthly_not_completed
        FROM measurements
        GROUP BY year_month
        ORDER BY year_month DESC;
      "
      @result = Measurement.connection.execute(@query)
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Not signed in"
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

Comment: you can add a ajax loader saying loading...

Comment: You need to use JavaScript to display a "loading" message, and simultaneously make an asynchronous request to your `monthly_measurements` endpoint. A good place to start would be reading about making asynchronous requests using JavaScript (ajax): http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#an-introduction-to-ajax

Comment: Is there any other way to do this without AJAX?

Comment: The select statement in the controller is taking time to execute. The page is not reached until the select finishes. So why I should put something in a page, some AJAX call which is not reached until the select statement is finished.

Comment: This is the reason I am looking to use a flash message in the controller instead of adding code to a page which never executed before the controller sends the result of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by making the display of the intermediary message "Processing ... " no longer necessary by reducing the controller query processing time with on order of magnitude.

I denormalized the `measurements` table by adding a column `year_month` of type text. The column is populated with the `yyyy-mm` part of the `scheduled_on` of each respective table row. The column `year_month` is indexed.

The total number of records in the table `measurements` is 120K+

I replaced also as necessary in all functions and queries the occurrence of `to_char(scheduled_on, 'yyyy-mm')` with `year_month`.

Everything (all related reports) now runs perfect and in a split of a second.